# Custom UIControl slider doesn't work when embedded in iOS13 modal viewController

Tags: modalviewcontroller, ios13, uicontrol

When I embed a custom UIControl inside a ViewController that's presented modally with the new iOS13 automatic style, `touchesCancelled` is called whenever a pan gesture moves more than a few points.

The native `UIKit` `UISlider` doesn't do this. You can pan a UISlider within an `automatic` style modal ViewController without issue.

UIScrollView has `touchesShouldCancel(in view: UIView)` where you can force it to allow touches in specified views but I can't find anything in the docs for this new style of modal presentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be in using overrides of the `UIControl` functions `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded`, and `touchesCancelled` to observe drags. These touch events can't be intercepted like is possible with `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` so there's no way to stop the modal drag from forcing `touchesCancelled`.

The answer seems to be: **don't use `UIControl` touch event methods**. Rather, - like other answers indicate works - use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and the delegate method `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin`.

The trouble all along was trying to use a UIControl as Apple documents say you should.

Answer (score 6):

You can implement `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` of `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` on your `UIControl` and return `false` if it is of `UIPanGestureRecognizer`

```swift
//MARK: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
extension RangeSlider: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    public override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return !(gestureRecognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer)
    }
}
```

Comment: `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` isn't called in response to the pan of the modally presented view

Answer (score 2):

If you use the range slider inside an `UITableViewCell`, this will catch the events from `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`. Although strange that `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` is not triggered here either. Is not optimal but maybe someone else has a new idea after noticing this.

```
extension RangeTableViewCell {
override func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    // Very hackish but there is no other option I've found for now
    // Consider using a custom modal presentation style and transition
    // this gesture actually makes the range slider call cancelTracking so we disable it
    if otherGestureRecognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer && otherGestureRecognizer.view?.className.contains("UIDropShadowView") ?? false {
        otherGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = false
    }
    return false
}
```

}

PS: I tried using the above func as `return otherGestureRecognizer is UIPanGestureRecognizer`; did not work either